# Share variables across modules in a pipeline

Tags: python, variables, pipeline

I'm currently working on a scientific project where I need to process an initial data set, filtering/merging/calcuating stuff. The pipeline requires a series of steps (~10), each of which is run within a different python module. Generally, the python module involves the creation of some intermediate file and eventually an outside bash command is run, calling outside programs. Ultimately, my question is how to handle the fairly large (and growing) number of variables (paths to files produced in the pipeline) that I need to keep track of step after step. Here's an oversimplified summary of my real `main.py`

```
import ld
import kinship
import PCA

def main(args):

    #LD pruning & build new plink file 
    args.ld_path = join(args.oPath,'ld/')
    ld.pruning(args)  
    args.plink_path = join(args.oPath,'plink_files/') 
    ld.build_plink_file(args)

    # build new plink file and calculate kinship
    pretty_print('KINSHIP')
    args.kinPath = join(args.oPath,'kinship/')
    kinship.download_king()
    kinship.kinship(args)

    #RUN PCA
    args.pca_path = join(args.oPath,'pca/')
    PCA.build_inliers(args)
    PCA.fast_pca_inliers(args)
    PCA.project_outliers(args)  



if __name__=='__main__':

    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Returning final list of variants after info_score filter and ld pruning")


    parser.add_argument('-b',"--bed", type=file_exists, help = "Folder in which the merged plink file is stored", required = True)
    parser.add_argument('-o',"--oPath",type = str, help = "folder in which to save the results", required = True)

    #LD PRUNING
    parser.add_argument('--ld',nargs=3,metavar = ('SIZE','STEP','THRESHOLD'),help ='size,step,threshold',required = True)


    #KINSHIP
    parser.add_argument('--degree',type=float,help='Degree for Kinship',default = 2)

    #PCA
    parser.add_argument('--pca-components',type=int,help='Components needed for pca',default = 20)

    main(args)
```

As you can see, in my pipeline i've ended up (ab)using the `argparse` class, "expanding" the parser creating new variables so that I can just pass the `args` class from one module to the other. I considered using also `settings`, but on top of some "official" outputs, there's also a bunch of intermediate files that are not passed just directly to the next step of the pipeline, but that might be required a few steps down the road, so I'd rather not have to define them all at once.

Is there a better/cleaner solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a configuration json?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably have a Config-Class in my first module and then pass an Instance around by pickling it.
Any values can simply be stored in the class dict.
It's easy to break, but for a simple approach it would probably do the trick...

```
import pickle

class Configuration:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.path = file_path

    def dump(self):
        with open(self.path, 'w+') as config_file:
            pickle.dump(self, config_file)

config = Configuration(r"C:\temp\config.file")
config.kinship_degree = 3

config.dump()

with open(r"C:\temp\config.file") as cf:
    restored_config = pickle.load(cf)

print restored_config.kinship_degree)
```

Otherwise I would probably wrap the different modules in a pipeline module, which instantiates module classes with the required parameters and runs them.